# making a text input appear at center not at the top of the page

Tags: javascript, html

guys i am new to html ... i want to make this `Username: <input type="text" name="Username" style=" -
margin-top: 200px; ">` appear at the center of the page not at the top .. i tried making the postion absolute and change the margin top but i found that only the empty text filed appears at center and the word "Username" still at the top .. so any help ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

write it into a div container. Dont forget to set height and weight to set it auto center

```
<div style="width:200px;height:1em;margin:auto;">Username <input type="text" name="username"/></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to wrap your entire line in a `span` tag.

This will allow you to reference all of the text rather than just the input.

So,

```
<span style="-margin-top: 200px;">Username: <input type="text" name="Username"></span>
```

should do the trick.

As for the positioning, you're probably looking for the [Absolute Center](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2013/08/09/absolute-horizontal-vertical-centering-css/) technique.

```
element {
  text-align: center;
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0;
}
```